# Prevent Default throwing no method error

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I'm fairly new when it comes to Javascript and I'm trying to create an audio playlist for an `<audio>` tag.

I'm currently stuck on what should be quite a simple stage of the process where I want the anchor's click event to be prevented to stop it from taking you to an new page to play the audio.

```
window.onload = function(){

    playlist = $('#playlist');

    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        $(e).preventDefault();
        alert('event prevented');   

    });

};
```

I keep getting the below error. I've checked and double checked the syntex but can't seem to get this to run. I must be missing something simple.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'preventDefault'
```

I've tried `$(this).preventDefault();`
and even `$('#playlist a').preventDafault();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$(e).preventDefault();
```

to

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Massive help thanks. Can't believe it all fell down from something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use e.preventDefault() (without $ and braces)

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/